# Laravel : select option

Tags: php, laravel

I have 2 selects in a form . The second select depends on the first.
In the output display

```
<option value="1" data-secid="2"> madint nasr</option>                                                                                                    
<option value="2" data-secid="2"> semoha</option>                                                                                                                      
<option value="3" data-secid="2"> montaza</option>                                                                                                        
<option value="4" data-secid="2"> marina</option>
```

`data-secid="2"` is not a normal id.

The code:

```
<select name="region_id "  class="form-control subsection" id="regions">
     @foreach( $regions as $keys => $relatedItem )
     <option value="{{ $keys }}"  {{ $keys == $region_id   }} data-secid="{{ $key }}" {{ $key == $city_id  }}> {{ is_json($relatedItem) ? getDefaultValueKey($relatedItem) :  $relatedItem}}</option>
     @endforeach
</select>
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @Daniel
data-secid="{{ $key }}"
in output display 
data-secid="2" is not a normal id.

Comment: Where does `$key` come from? Your foreach loop uses `$keys` as the key attribute. Shouldn't you use that instead?

Comment: come from $city_id
{{ $key == $city_id  }}
but not run 
what the correct code if i want to get $city_id from database

Comment: @Daniel 
come from $city_id 
{{ $key == $city_id }} 
but not run what the correct code if i want to get $city_id from database